# Trouble with a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could somebody please help me solve the differential equation.I entered the equation in various online differential equation calculators but they said the input in invalid

$qv_oe^\frac{-bt}{m}B-\frac{mv_o^2e^\frac{-2bt}{m}}{r} =m\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}$

as $t→\infty,r→0$
I am posting the question from which this equation arose as follows
[image]
I am assuming small values of the constant b

$m\frac{dv}{dt}=-bv$
solving this we get that

$v(t)=v_0e^\frac{-bt}{m}$
now

$ma_{radial}=qv(t)B-\frac{mv^2(t)}{r}$

now substituting v(t) I arrived at the above equation.
please help!

Comment: Could you share the original problem please? It looks like a physics problem. It may be helpful to approach the problem intuitively, rather than a mathematical way.

Comment: sure I can do that

Comment: For readability, I suggest that you rewrite as $$r''=\left(\frac ar+b\right)e^{-t}$$ (with a rescaling of time).

Comment: And fix your input to the calculators !

Comment: I rewrote it as$ r''(t)=e^{-ct}({\frac{be^{-ct}}{r} + d})$ and entered it into wolfram alpha, yet  it isn't showing an answer .It says computation time exceeded

Comment: Mh, you silently changed the equation, bad idea !

Comment: No way to solve this equation with a closed form, at least using Mathematica. You wouldn't get an answer from WA even if you pay, because WA is based on Mathematica. If you had numerical data, I could try to solve it approximately

Comment: i erroneously included a factor of 2 in the exponent in the first edit As i had lazily cop pasted it from the first term.I have fixed it now, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the usual notation we get
$$m\mathbf {\dot v}=q \mathbf v \times \mathbf B-b \mathbf v$$
Now assume that $\mathbf B$ is in the z direction (that is $\mathbf B = B \mathbf k$), and that the particle is launched in the x – y plane. Express $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf {\dot v}$ in terms of $\mathbf i$ and $\mathbf j$ and you will have two equations each mixing $v_x, \dot{v}_x, v_y, \dot{v}_y$. It's easy to eliminate (say) $v_x\ \text{and}\ \dot{v}_x$, leaving a second order ODE in $v_y$ with constant coefficients.